# How do I change CSS when an Angular object exists?

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I am changing an Angular input component's CSS using the .ng-valid[required] method.  This component is validating an email string pattern using:

```
pattern="[^@]+@[^@]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,} and changing the colour.
```

Here is the template:

```
<input *ngIf="(type == 'email') && showValidation" type={{type}} placeholder={{placeholder}} name={{name}} required class="textfield {{align}}" pattern="[^@]+@[^@]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}" [(ngModel)]='inputText' (keyup)="onValueChange(inputText)" (blur)="onBlur($event)">
```

How do I change the colours using CSS if I find that the user already exists in the database?

```
.ng-valid[required],
.ng-valid.required {
  border-left: 5px solid #4fd987;
  /* green */
}
.ng-invalid:not(form) {
  border-left: 5px solid #e55a5a;
  /* red */
}
```

This is the custom input component:

```
<wf-input tabindex="0"  #username placeholder="Email address" type="email" showValidation="true" (inputEvnt)='user.emailAddress = $event'
            (inputEvnt)='validateInputs()' (blur)="checkEmail(user.emailAddress)"  name="registration-form_email"></wf-input>
```

If the email exists this should validate as "true" and I want to change the color of the "border-left".

I found this example which uses AngularJS (1.x) using ngUnique but it doesn't work with Angular 2+.

[Example](https://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/form-validation-the-angularjs-way/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add  [style.border-left-color]="emailValidated ? 'green' : 'red'"

```
<wf-input tabindex="0"
    #username 
    placeholder="Email address"
    type="email" showValidation="true"
    (inputEvnt)='user.emailAddress = $event'
    (inputEvnt)='validateInputs()'
    (blur)="checkEmail(user.emailAddress)"
    name="registration-form_email"
    [style.border-left-color]="emailValidated ? 'green' : 'red'"> // Add here
</wf-input>
```

Comment: Can u please tell me in more details. where should i add? thank u in advance.